# Roblox WidthScale not being affected

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I'm trying to make a potion where you get thin when you drink it, but when I try the code below, it doesn't work. No errors, no warnings, no nothing.

```lua
return function(Player)
    local HumanoidDescription = Player.Character.Humanoid:GetAppliedDescription()
    HumanoidDescription.WidthScale /= 3
    Player.Character.Humanoid:ApplyDescription(HumanoidDescription)
    wait(120)
    local HumanoidDescription2 = Player.Character.Humanoid:GetAppliedDescription()
    HumanoidDescription2.WidthScale *= 3
    Player.Character.Humanoid:ApplyDescription(HumanoidDescription2)
end
```